# I need to bind data click on rowcommand event of gridview in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

```
<ItemTemplate>
 <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("News_Title") %>' 
                 CommandName="Submit" 
                 CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID") %>' 
                 onclick="LinkButton1_Click" >LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
```

DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'ID'

Comment: There will be no column named "ID" in the DataSource.